# CCLabelTTF Vertically Align (Cocos2D)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, text-formatting

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Vertically Center Me About Myself" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 300) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:20];
label.position = ccp(screenwidth/2, screenheight/2);
[layer addChild:label];
```

So I create the above label and add it to my layer. Due to the `dimensions` parameter, the text does wrap correctly, but only the *very first line* of text is centered vertically (eg only the very first line of text has exactly 50% of the character height above the half screen mark, and exactly 50% of the character height beneath the half screen mark:

```
.
.
---Vertically---
   Center Me
  About Myself
```

Where the ----- denotes 1/2 screen (ignore the dots, they are just there for stackoverflow formatting). How do I get it to dynamically center the text about whatever  the center of itself? So for example in this case, I would want 'Center Me' to be what is centered. If my string only contained 'Vertically' I would expect that to be centered, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Try to write after the first string:

```
label.anchorPoint = ccp([label boundingBox].size.width / 2, [label boundingBox].size.height / 2);
```

The second possible solution is to set its position directly upper according to the label boundingBox size

Comment: anchorPoint actually uses points (instead of pixels) in CC2D 0.98+, so I had to change this to: `label.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);`. By default, the anchor point is already `0.5, 0.5` but by resetting it after specifying the newly created string, it properly repositions it. =]